# How to encrypt or decrypt text file using 2 parallel arrays in java?

Tags: arrays, encryption

I have two arrays:

```
char[] A={"A","B","C"};
char[] B={"1","2","3"};
```

How can I decrypt A array to B. For example, if I write ABA it should become 121.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple dictionary that maps the values you want "B" to the values you give "A".

You can Google "java dictionary"